# iscsiadm hangs and tcpdump shows nothing

Tags: linux, networking, storage, blocking, iscsi

I am troubleshooting `iscsiadm`.

```
iscsiadm --mode discovery --portal 10.144.35.235 --type sendtargets --discover
```

The command mentioned above blocks and does nothing. I've cleared ipvs and iptables.

```
ipvsadm -C && iptables --flush
```

When I run `tcpdump`, no packets are shown.

```
root@master:~# tcpdump host 10.144.35.235
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s20f0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
1 packet dropped by interface
```

Some config:

```
root@master:~# cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi
InitiatorName=iqn.2019-05.net.packet:device.7670d17c
```

`/etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf` - https://pastebin.com/ZGcwNbBP

`/etc/multipath.conf` - https://pastebin.com/NEFeM1nf

**Would anybody know what could be possible causes of `iscsiadm` blocking? What does it wait for?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest version from the master branch helped - commit f71581bd641dc26d330cb8b97e5ec272dd08f811. Get it [here](https://github.com/open-iscsi/open-iscsi/). Every released version <= 2.0.877 has the issue. It was bug in the software, not a configuration error.

Comment: It might be helpful to mention what this latest version was, and what version you were having issues with

Comment: Edited @JourneymanGeek